# Gracefully ending a python program using supervisor

Tags: python, supervisord

I am writing a python program which I would run using supervisor. The program basically does the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        run()
```

where run function does a simple task of getting something from database (`mysqlDB`) and send that in an email.

I want to write the program such that when I use

`supervisorctl stop program`

the mysql connection should close and  a propper log for shutdown is done.

Is there any way I can handle the stop command in my python script.

Comment: You will need to capture the signal sent from supervisor https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: Where/How do I capture these signals?

Comment: I did include a link in my answer, then there is also google which has all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the signal unit to receive signals from the OS, which is what supervisor will do.  Example code below is NOT tested.  At all.

```
import signal

keep_going = True

def my_shutdown_handler(signum, frame):
    # set a flag to exit your loop or call what you need to exit gracefully
    keep_going = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, my_shutdown_handler) 
    while keep_going:
        run()
```

See more and much cleaner examples here:

[How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully)