# Python Application won't terminate when user shuts computer down

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I recently created a standalone python application with pyinstaller for OS X. I have encountered a problem when I try to shutdown(or restart) the computer. The computer won't shutdown until the application is forced quit.

What I would like the application to do is terminate once I wish to shut down my computer, just like safari or other applications would. Its okay for the application to completely restart when the computer is booted again it does not have to resume from where it was last left on.

All I want the application to do is to automatically terminate once the user clicks shut down. At the moment the user has to click shut down and then cmd+option+esc and force quit the application THEN the computer shuts down. Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a signal handler to catch SIGTERM.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully

Comment: @PaulRooney Strange. Isn't SIGTERM sent to all apps at shutdown and cause them to quit in any case?

Comment: could you give me more details on how to do so? @PaulRooney

Comment: not working @Paul Rooney

Comment: I have no knowledge of osx in particular, but it seems you might want to look at `launchd`.

Comment: I have a launch daemon that starts my program on startup @PaulRooney