# How Can Python Handle systemctl stop?

Tags: python, linux, systemd

I have a Python script that is running as a service. It writes to disk. If a user calls systemctl stop on the service, I would like to handle the command in my own way to reduce the risk of file corruption.

How can I catch the systemctl stop command?

My file in /usr/lib/systemd/system is:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /srv/go.py
User=jon
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

My Python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import datetime
import threading

def worker():
    while True:

        with open('/tmp/go.txt', 'a') as f:
            s = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) + '\n'
            f.write(s)
            print(s)

            time.sleep(1)


if __name__=='__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
```

Comment: maybe this can help with your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Comment: At first glance, the kill signal isn't the problem...
Your thread doesn't have a return/exit condition, and it isn't daemonized so won't automatically go away when the main thread does.
Try ```t.daemon = True``` before starting the thread...

Answer (score 21):

As described in [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html), processes will receive `SIGTERM` and then, immediately, `SIGHUP`. After some time, `SIGKILL` will be send.

All signals, as well as strategy of sending them, can be changed in relevant service file.

See [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18499497/3552063) to see how handle these signals in your Python program.