# Selenium is there a way to prevent ctrl+c to close browser window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch, keyboardinterrupt

In my program I got something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options()) #calling the driver
driver.get(website) #opening the website
try:
    while True:
        do_something() #Here I do a couple of things
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    #When I'm done with the while loop above(the goal is to be able to stop at any point of the loop) I use ctrl+c
    pass
#Here the program continues but selenium closes the window even though I didn't call for driver.quit().
```

While it successfully stops the while loop and don't end the program itself, selenium closes the window browser. Is there a way to prevent selenium from closing the window?

Comment: Selenium will not close the browser if you did not tell it to do so. We'll need to see more of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original post and added more information. The point is that I want to successfully leave the while loop at any point. I achieved that with ctrl+c but that closes the window browser as well and I would like to keep that open.

Comment: Hmm... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135888/python-selenium-ctrlc-closes-chromedriver

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it doesn't even open a browser and crashes right after.

Comment: What do you mean under "I want to successfully leave the while loop at any point", do you have specific condition, or end while randomly

Answer (score 2):

When you are done with the while loop instead of using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> you can easily break out as follows:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, WebDriverException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options()) #calling the driver
driver.get(website) #opening the website
while True:
    try:
        do_something() #Here I do a couple of things
    except (NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException, TimeoutException):
        break
# Here the program continues and selenium doesn't closes the window even
```

Comment: I did face the same issue and needed to be able to break, but unfortunately, it does not seem to be working with PyCharm / Ipython