# Container crashes when python application sent SIGTERM

Tags: python, docker, signals

I am running a docker container which has a python application that spawns other processes. I am using signals to try to gracefully shut down the python application and all of the spawned processes.  When I send SIGTERM using the template from [How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully) the entire container terminates.  If I remove the logic of managing spawned processes, then the application closes normally and the container remains running (but my other processes are still running).  I have tried this with other signals as well, but the result was the same.

```
Entering loop to listen for sigterm
^CLeaving loop
Killing 188 devices
/bin/sh: line 1:    31 Killed                  /bin/bash
```

Comment: Please post the output you're receiving from the containerized process, including any stack traces and debug output from the Docker daemon. Really *any* output that you receive will be useful.

Comment: Added basic output. Will try to get more verbose log.