# Python gracefully stop a script from Laravel/Php

Tags: php, python

I'm looking for a way to gracefully exit from a long running python script which I launch from my Laravel app.

My actual process to do so is:

- From Laravel set a 'script_state' to 1 in a MySql table database
- Launch the python script via `shell_exec`
- The python scripts periodically check the 'script_state' by a MySql query. If it is changed to 0 (intentionally from my Laravel app) then it gracefully exit the script

Retrieving the `pid` from the `shell_exec` and then kill could have been an option but I actually wan't the script to stop and exit gracefully.

My actual config works but I'm looking for a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Retrieving the `pid` from the `shell_exec` and then kill could have been an option but I actually wan't the script to stop and exit gracefully.

This is probably your best bet. You can use [`SIGTERM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) to politely ask the script to exit:

> The `SIGTERM` signal is a generic signal used to cause program termination. Unlike `SIGKILL`, this signal can be blocked, handled, and ignored. It is the normal way to politely ask a program to terminate.

This is effectively what happens when you click the close button in a GUI application.

In your Python code you can handle `SIGTERM` using the [`signal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) with whatever cleanup logic you want, then exit:

> ```
> import signal, os
>
> def handler(signum, frame):
>     print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
>     raise OSError("Couldn't open device!")
>
> # Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
> signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
> signal.alarm(5)
>
> # This open() may hang indefinitely
> fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)
>
> signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
> ```

See also [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464349/354577) for a class that cleans up before exiting.