# Python threading: Is there a way to detect a join() call in a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pthread-join

I have created a program that runs **X** number of threads which all need to be able to be closed down by the main thread. Currently I can stop the program so that each thread will be abruptly killed. I want to be able to detect the close and handle it more gracefully. To do this I want to use the `join()` function, which waits for the threads to finish. The issue is that the threads don't have a set end and so calling `join()` would mean that the main thread will wait forever for the threads to end.

So the question is. Is there a way to detect a `join()` call in a thread and write a customized response to it?

Comment: Why do you want `join` to be the signal? Why not use a mechanism designed for sending messages between threads?

Comment: That would work just as well. I'm relatively new to python threading. Would you mind pushing me in the right direction regarding passing messages between threads?

Comment: For this particular use case, an [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the stop signal outside your threads (with `signal` module, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464349/4271929)), set a flag on your threads asking them to stop processing and call `join` in your main thread.