# Python script that can be externally terminated in a graceful manner

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

My server generates every minute ~30 xml files, and I would like to do a sftp to transfer files from server to my machine.
I would like to use Paramiko to do an sftp, I am getting what I want with the bellow script:

```
import paramiko
import os
import time
filename = "addresses.text"
localpath= "******"
serverpath= "*******"


while True:
    try:
        current_time = time.time()
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = f.readlines()
        for ipAddr in data:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(ipAddr,username="root",password="root")
            sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
            for element in sftp.listdir(serverpath):
                if element.endswith(".xml"):
                    try:
                        print(os.stat(localpath+f))
                    except:
                        try:
                            creation_time = sftp.stat(serverpath+element).st_mtime
                            if (current_time+3400 - creation_time) / (3600) <= 1:
                                sftp.get(serverpath+element,localpath+element)
                        except:
                            print(Exception)
            sftp.close()
            ssh.close()
        for f in os.listdir(localpath):
            creation_time = os.path.getctime(localpath+f)
            print((3600+current_time - creation_time) / (3600))
            if (3600+current_time - creation_time) / (3600) >= 1.8:
                os.unlink(localpath+f)

    except OSError as e:
        print(OSError)
```

I would like to do something like `start sftp.py` and then run my script in the background. And when I want to stop the connection just run `stop sftp.py`

Comment: What's wrong with `while True:`? - Except that you do not need to reconnect in every iteration and that you should probably add some delay between iterations.

Comment: In fact, this script will be added to a jenkins job in the future to install a VM and then run this script to send files to an appropriate machine. The problem is with my script I can run it but if I would like to stop this process I should do an ps -edf I think. That's why I am looking for something easier to automated the process in the futur.

Comment: So you question is only, how to implement a graceful stopping of a Python script - i.e. your question is not about SFTP or Paramiko, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How this is usually implemented is that a running process stores its PID to a file.

And then you can implement another script (or a parameter to your existing script - like my example below does) that reads the PID from the file and terminates that process.

You can even [make the termination graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18499497/850848).

```
import signal
import time
import os
import sys

pidfile = "sftp.pid"

if (len(sys.argv) > 1) and (sys.argv[1] == "stop"):
    if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
        with open(pidfile, "r") as f:
            pid = int(f.read())
        print("stopping sftp process {0}".format(pid))
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    else:
        print("sftp is not running")
    sys.exit()

class GracefulKiller:
    kill_now = False
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self,signum, frame):
        self.kill_now = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = os.getpid()
    print("sftp is starting with pid {0}".format(str(pid)))
    with open(pidfile, "w") as f:
        f.write(str(pid))

    killer = GracefulKiller()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("doing something in a loop ...")
        if killer.kill_now:
            break

    print "End of the program. I was killed gracefully :)"

    os.remove(pidfile)
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin, I used finally a shell script, but your solution is the best one ;)