# How to process SIGTERM gracefully in R?

Tags: r, sigterm, resource-cleanup

In Python, one can process SIGTERM using an answer like the one here: [How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully).

How can we do the same thing in R?

Answer (score 1):

My own investigations have shown that none of the usual mechanisms (`on.exit()`, `reg.finalizer()`, or the `.Last()` handler) are triggered when R receives SIGTERM.

I wrote a very small, silly package to circumvent R's behaviour by installing a signal handler directly: https://github.com/atheriel/sigterm.

But it's probably worth bringing this up with the R developers as well.