# How can I stop the running command in linux without knowing the pid?

Tags: python, linux, process, kill

I know there are several ways to kill a process if I know the process id.

But similar to ctrl+C in keyboard interrupt, looking for such interrupt using a command.

Comment: How will you know which program to kill without an identifier? How is the program to be killed being run in relation to your program?

Comment: You can search the PID by searching the process name in the process tree (like `pgrep`). You use [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) for that.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE What if the current command is running in the terminal will I know the pid of that process in other terminal if I open a new terminal and run psutil?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully)

Comment: In a server, as I know, there is only one process tree. So, yes you can find your process, even if it is opened in another terminal.

Comment: Maybe `killall <program_name>` will do?  Disclaimer: that may kill more than you would have liked.

Answer (score 0):

use this Command to kill the process(
killall -s 9 [process name]  )