# how to still use a function when I manually kill the specific .py script?

Tags: python, ubuntu, process

I wrote a code that checks files and send mails if someone opens and access a specific file
here is the code:

```
import atexit
import smtplib
from os import stat
import signal


email = "******"
password = "******"
message = "File has been touched you are busted"
f = "check.txt"

file_last_access_time = stat(f).st_atime


def sendemail():
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(email, password)
    s.sendmail(email, email, message)
    print('Mail Sent')
    s.quit()
    return;



while True:
    current_access_time = stat(f).st_atime
    if file_last_access_time != current_access_time:
        sendemail()
        break



atexit.register(sendemail())
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sendemail())
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sendemail())
```

I am running this .py script on Ubuntu through terminal. I am trying to find a way to make the code still send me the email even if I use kill{pid}. When I am killing the process, it doesn't send me an email would love to get some help to make it work

Comment: Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107939/how-to-restart-the-python-script-automatically-if-it-is-killed-or-dies) thread

Comment: hey that doesn't answer my question i want to be able to still send an email(call a function) if my script is terminated by kill p{id}

Comment: You don't. Functions don't exist separately from the process that executes them. What you want, I think, is a way to run the script in the background, with something that monitors the script to restart it if it ever exits.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully). By your description I assume you want to do something in response to kill signals.