# Python Quart | Wait for create_task() to complete before exit

Tags: python, quart

I have created an application using Quart, it has a background task that performs tasks such as data analysis and writing reports.  When I end the application with ctrl-c the background thread is instantly killed, even if it's in the middle of an IO task, how do I get the framework to wait for the background task to finish please?

Update:
My initial implementation was to use to have run() execute thread, I was trying to get away from this since asyncio supports the creation of tasks (create_task) and it seems like the better way, although I don't honestly know.

```
class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self._is_initialised : bool = False
        self._shutdown_completed : bool = False
        self._shutdown_requested : bool = False

    async def run(self) -> None:
        while not self._shutdown_requested and self._is_initialised:
            try:
                await self._main_loop()
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break

        self._shutdown_completed = True

    def stop(self) -> None:
        print("Shutting down...")
        self._shutdown_requested = True
        print('Shutdown has completed')


import asyncio
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)
SERVICE_APP = None

@app.before_serving
async def startup() -> None:
    asyncio.create_task(SERVICE_APP.run())

@app.after_serving
async def shutdown() -> None:
    SERVICE_APP.stop()

SERVICE_APP = Application(app)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully)

Comment: @JulienSorin My original implementation used a thread, if that is the only solution where the task waits for completion I will use it, but it seems to go against how asyncio should be used as you can create tasks using the library.

Comment: Have you tried a background task, https://quart.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/how_to_guides/background_tasks.html?

Comment: @pgjones Thank you that worked if you want to make it an answer.  I didn't realise this method was still available, I incorrectly assumed it was deprecated a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background task is likely the better choice here as Quart will delay shutdown (for as long as the ASGI server allows) whilst waiting for the background tasks to stop, [see docs](https://quart.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/how_to_guides/background_tasks.html):

```py
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)

async def background_task():
    # Actual code to run in the background

@app.before_serving
async def startup() -> None:
    app.add_background_task(background_task)
```