# Get Heroku SIGTERM signal in pycord Discord bot

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py, pycord

My Discord bot is hosted on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). I'm trying to get the ["SIGTERM" signal](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown) that heroku sends before restarting the dyno in my Discord bot so i can save some stuff to my database before the dyno gets terminated after 30seconds. How would i do that?

Comment: Why don't you just save to your database immediately?

Comment: @stijndcl because i save the collected chat exp locally and then bulk write it to the db collection every 30min. Its a Discord Server with 20k Members so the chat is active and saving the exp after every message wouldnt be that good ig.

Comment: And is there a reason that the solution in this question doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully (using `signal` to attach a callback to that specific signal)