# How not to start docker container on system reboot?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, jobs

I have `compose.yml` file:

```
  api:
    restart: on-failure
    command: uvicorn app:app
    ...

  jobs:
    restart: on-failure
    command: python job.py
    ...
```

`job.py`:

```
import asyncio
from prometheus_client import start_http_server

async def background(sio):
    await asyncio.gather(...) # <- there are many tasks with while True


start_http_server(5000)
asyncio.run(background(sio))
```

It works okay. After stopping everything turns off. But when I restart system, `jobs` container starting automatically. Why?! `api` is not starting, but why `jobs` starting?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess would be that when Docker sends a SIGTERM to python, it results in a non-zero exit code (an error) but uvicorn doesn't, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: If that is the case, you can gracefully process the SIGTERM with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

I think Docker is just trying to run the containers that were running before the system shutdown. Maybe try to change `restart` policy to `no` to prevent restarting on startup?

```
  jobs:
    restart: no
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy) `unless-stopped` is probably the right option.

```yaml
  jobs:
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: python job.py
```